# arm assembly : '#define' risk

Tags: gcc, assembly, arm, gnu-assembler

In ARM assembly

```
bic r0, r0, #0x1f
```

works fine. now I want `#define MODE 0x1f` and change above code to `bic r0,r0, #MODE`.

There is a risk here. If you forget include the header file where `#define MODE 0x1f` is defined, gcc assembles without complain, but the result is wrong, it turns out compiler translates `#MODE` as 0.

I proved out the problem is caused by "`#`".  how could I tell preprocessor not to handle "#" as this `#` is used by assembly?

Thanks

Comment: you can't use #define in ARM assembly

Answer (score 4):

1. I *think* the most recent ARM docs specify # in immediates as optional, so you could try using bic r0, MODE.
2. You can use assembly-level defines:

   .equ MODE, 0x1F

   bic r0,r0, #MODE